# Ayuda con getter en otra clase

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo algún problema para poder ejecutar un código para eliminar todos los objetos de una lista que tienen un estado de una enumeración AnimalStatus = DEAD.

El código que he utilizado hasta ahora es:

```
public void removeDeadItems() {     
    for(int i = 0; i < getNumberItems(); i++) {
        if(getItem(i).getStatus() == AnimalStatus.DEAD) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
```

}

El problema es que el método getStatus() que va después de getItem() antes estaba en la misma clase  que el método getItem (Clase Item) pero ahora he tenido que mover getStatus a otra clase (Animal) y me aparece el siguiente error: "The method getStatus() is undefined for the type Item"

¿Como podría hacer que funcione para poder eliminar los objetos como antes utilizando el metodo getStatus() de la clase Animal?

Comment: Pero cómo es tu jerarquía de clases? Qué relación hay entre Item y Animal?

Comment: Item es la superclase y Animal es la subclase que hereda de Item. El problema es que Item no debe tener el método getStatus() porque ya lo tiene la clase animal.

Comment: Bueno, pero la herencia no funciona así. Si el status es un atributo de Item, tiene que estar en Item y Animal lo heredará.

Answer (score 0):

Si UNICAMENTE Animal debe tener el metodo getStatus(), agregalo en Animal, si ambos deben tenerlo (Item u otras clases que heredan del mismo), lo agregas en Item y NO en Animal, ya que al tenerlo el padre todos sus subclases heredan ese metodo.